# Unable to setup Neo4jPHP in WAMP

Tags: php, neo4jphp

I tried to setup Neo4jPHP in WAMP. I am getting error when I run the `index.php file.` 
I have uploaded the files for reference `@ http://ilovec.in/neo4jphp/` and the file names are

```
Setup directory structure : dirtree.xml
index.php file as text : index.php.txt
error output : output.html
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error "cUrl extension not enabled/installed" states, you have not installed or activated the curl extension.

Check your php.ini and search for

`;extension=php_curl.dll`

and remove the `;`

`extension=php_curl.dll`

Then restart your http server.

If you don't have such an entry, either enter it manually (maybe works if extension is installed) or install it (depending on your host, is it windows/linux?)